# customizing ZfcUser

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

What I would like to do is to add some more properties(fields) for a registering user to fill out for example: we have a display name by provided by default and i would like to have some more like, place of birth, birth date and so on..

I created my own entity class and made ZfcUser working with it (to be more specific: i added some protected variables, getters and setters methods).

My problem is that i dont really know what to do next. I know that i should obviously add some elements to forms and i can do it but how can i "let know" zfcuser that i have some more variables in entity class so it can work with database well.

btw. i cant understand how this module is working for example where exactly it runs scripts which work with database

Comment: I have a small blog writeup here that should help you http://circlical.com/blog/2013/4/1/l5wftnf3p7oks5561bohmb9vkpasp6

Answer (score 4):

Check out [CdliUserProfile](https://github.com/cdli/CdliUserProfile) it's an existing extension for ZfcUser with UserProfile support (and therefore custom properties). Check that code or use the module itself ;)

Comment: It's written by one of the co-contributors to ZfcUser, and may eventually be incorporated into Zfc.